# Linking pages together

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working with a knowledge graph where each unique subject has a number of properties. Each subject has a unique URI ex lets take this website: https://www.deutsche-digitale-bibliothek.de/person/gnd/118575775?lang=en

for a particular person

I know it is a stupid question but I am new to html and javascript. So if I have a link to that URI do I have to create an html file for each subject? What do /person/gnd/... refer to exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, every slash after the domain is considered a route or pattern. The way that route works depends on the configuration of the web server.

**Host-Based**

Host based routing relies on the web server to route/forward the traffic, and in most cases it is in fact using a physical directory on the filesystem. This is the traditional way web applications worked.

**Path-Based**

Path based routing uses what is commonly referred to as a "front controller" to route the request. In this scenario, the web server routes/forwards all traffic to one file (commonly index.xxx). Inside that file you have an application router that matches patterns based on the URI. If it finds a match, that particular code will run and the result is returned.

Here is a link that also explains it: https://dzone.com/articles/the-three-http-routing-patterns-you-should-know

Comment: Is there anywhere I can see how I can code using path based routing?

Comment: @Martha - well that would depend on the language you plan to use which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: I am using javascript

Comment: @Martha - Javascript is a client side language, you would need to use a server side language such as PHP or python for this.

Comment: I actually am piecing the information. I found the index file you are referring to and is in php but not sure what I have to fix to redirect the pattern of the URI to a particular html file

Comment: Well it can get complicated, there is honestly no simple answer. The easiest path is to use a framework like Slim that can do the routing for you, otherwise you would have to code it from the ground up. You also need a directive on the web server to forward all the traffic to index.php. Do some research on the internet and then ask the questions you are unsure about.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have a link to that URI do I have to create an html file for each subject?

Thank god no! An URL like `http://example.com/some/path` is basically a protocol (`http://`) + a server name (`example.com`) + a path (`/some/path`). The old-school way was to indeed have a resource for each path, but that is not required: given a certain path, the server is free to respond with whatever it wants.

I can't say that for sure but I *highly suspect* `deutsche-digitale-bibliothek.de` to have preformatted page for all people, and then custom person infos is being loaded thereafter. The bottom line is that it is both unecessary and not advised to, in the case when a lot of similar pages exist, have one HTML file for each of them.

> What do /person/gnd/... refer to exactly?

That is the path. That's the segment that is sent to the server as part of the URL as specified in the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Thank you for you answer as you understood exactly what I was confused about. So how is the html file not in the URL ex: http://host/RegisterResult.html?id=http://natarchives.com.mt/archivalresource/R494Vol1  I was expecting that the single HTML file representing a person and being populated with the person be in the URI as /Person.html...or something like this

Comment: As I said, the server does whatever he wants - there might be `.html` in the URL, but the servers sends a JSON file. There might be [no `.html` in the URL yet an HTML file is served](http://instagram.com). The 'populated HTML file' does not need to appear in the path, it all happens internally in the server.